# Syntax error in Union All of recursive CTE postgresql

Tags: recursion, syntax-error, postgresql-9.3

I have been struggling to fit in my logic into recursive cte as it seems its the best approach to solve the hierarchization problem using SQL. On running a this structure below I am getting

> syntax error at or near "DROP"
>   LINE 7: create temp table allnewreleases AS (SELECT mc.changeset_id,...

Was wondering can we create and drop temp tables inside the recursive part of the recursive cte?

```
create temp table maincompo AS(SELECT * from X)

create temp table allnew AS (SELECT * FROM Y inner join maincompo)
--anchor query starts--
(WITH RECURSIVE mainquery AS ((SELECT * FROM allnew )
--anchor query ends--   

 UNION ALL

 DROP TABLE maincompo
 DROP TABLE allnew

 create temp table maincompo AS(SELECT * from X inner join mainquery)
 create temp table allnew AS (SELECT * FROM Y inner join maincompo)
 SELECT * from allnew )

 SELECT * from mainquery)
```

Is something like this possible??, keeping in mind that the temp tables within Union ALL has to be created every something gets appended to anchor query from the recursive query.

Comment: You code does not make sense to me. Why do you have two different queries for the table `allnew`? You can only have one query for the source of a CREATE TABLE AS. And you can't have any DDL statements inside a CTE at all (regardless whether it's recursive or not). Maybe you should take a step back and explain the actual underlying problem you are trying  to solve (unrelated, but: there is no need to put the query for a CTAS between parentheses)

Comment: Can I have DML statements inside the CTE? And I am actually avoiding to post the actual query here. Its too big. I have Set of sql statements that access data , after the *answer from the final query* is obtained I need to *repeat the same steps with answers from the final query*

Comment: DML is possible: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING you can also define more than one CTE in a single query

Comment: So, I can make CTE under UNION ALL section as well?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Again: you should describe the actual problem you are trying to solve by supplying the table setup, sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://pastebin.com/ZGUs4inY maybe?